# Using jQuery to scroll to the top of a clicked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I've searched the web at length for a solution and come very close, but I'm hoping someone smarter than I can perfect this. When I click a div, I would like the top of said div to scroll to the top of the browser window. The current code snippet causes a parent div with the id "centered" to scroll to the top, but I would like each child div to scroll to its own top without having to write out an instance for every single div.

```
toggle:function(divid){ //public method
if (typeof divid=="object")
    divid=divid[0]
this.showhide(divid, "toggle")
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$('#centered').position().top}, 600);
```

}

Can anyone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: id `divid` the ID of the element you'd like to scroll to ?

Comment: It's a variable defined as this.currentid = divid;

Comment: Are the child divs inside the centered div, and do they also have scrollable content (overflow: scroll-y)? Adding a screenshot might make this clearer.

Comment: The child divs are inside the centered div, yes. They do not have scrollable content. I'm not sure how to show screenshots, but basically the 'centered' div is wrapping the child divs that have ids such as 'sbc', 'hol', and 'pac' (abbreviated names of my categories). Hopefully this explanation doesn't complicate the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what 'divid' represents, this is a fairly generic example that probably won't directly fit your scenario. However, assuming 'divid' is the id value or an object representing the div you should be able to do something like this:

```
toggle:function(divid) {
    if (typeof divid == 'object') {
        divid = $(divid[0]); // Assumes a jQuery object (not very robust)
    } else {
        divid = $('#' + divid);
    }

    this.showhide(divid, "toggle"); // May break depending if it accepts the jQuery object
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: divid.offset().top }, 600);
}
```

If 'this' is a reference to the div in question you can just swap in $(this) instead of using divid.

Note this code is not very robust so should be correctly altered to account for whatever divid really is. Also note - don't forget your semi-colons.